# How to use the Google-Calendar-API

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to create an android-program that creates, deletes, and updates a Google Calendar with my google account.

I have already read the Google Calendar API page on the Google Developer site 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ but i didn't understand how to add a calendar and sync it with my google account.

On this page: http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default is a google-calendar-android-sample and i wanted to ask how to implement it or are there any other implemented and finished projects ?

I have no idea which way is the best and i wanted to ask which way the best is to add a google calendar and sync it with my google account.

I have also tried to create a calendar with the calendarview, but i had problems with creating events i was not able to create events with the calendarview.

I hope this was enough information to understand my question.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific in the description? Which exact problems do you have? What is the problem with the sample?

Answer (score 1):

CalendarProvider is currently the recommended way to access Calendar API on Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html